# Pylucene and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pylucene

I'm using pylucene to build a index that will be used in a multiprocessing python program.

When I try to search in the index the execution is blocked when I use QueryParser.parse or IndexSearcher.search methods.

The block doesn't happen all the time and it happens with distinct searches in the first seconds of the execution.

What I'm doing wrong? What is the best way to use multiprocessing and pylucene?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem.

The program is blocked when I import the nltk module. This only happend in a multiprocess execution.

I guess that nltk also uses java libraries and they are messing with jcc.

Comment: Fairly specific problem that likely won't affect many others, but have a +1 for coming back and answering the question!